# Orders in the additive group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the orders of [5], and [12] in the additive group modulo 18? 
 I want know if what I am doing is correct. Here is my attempt 
 [5] + [5] =[10] 
 [5] + [5] + [5]= [15] 
 [5]+ [5] + [5] + [5]= [20]=[2] 
 based on these few steps, do I use this process? I came up with 18 when using [5]. Am I right? 
 If you need definitons, just ask.

Comment: Since $5$ and $18$ are coprime, $5$ _generates_ the group (recall Bezout's identity), so its order must be $18$.

Comment: yeah but the process takes a while based on my notes. Somebody just gave me simpler way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks fine, although there is a shortcut.

The order of $n$ in the additive group $\mathbb Z_n$ is $\frac{18}{gcd(n,18)}$. So the order of $5$ is $\frac{18}{1}$ and the order of $12$ is $\frac{18}{6}=3$.

Comment: so use the gcd to make it simple? Your way seems much quicker.Thanks

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: can you give me the simply way for the multiplicative form also? I need to find its order of [4] in the group modulo 7. Its tedious doing it by hand in the multiplicative form

Comment: @behold sadly no such easy formula exists for the multiplicative order

Comment: so I did the multiplicative of [4] modulo 7 and I got $[4]^3=[64]=[1]$. I think that is the correct way to do it

Comment: yup, the answer is always a divisor of $\varphi(n)$ by the way (where $n$ is the modulus).

Comment: Okay. I am on the right track but $[4]^4$ is giving me trouble. I got 4 as an answer for that

Answer (score 2):

The order of $a$ modulo $18$  is the smallest $r$ such that $ra$ is a multiple of $18$, i.e. is a multiple of both $18$ and $a$. In other words, $ra$ is the l.c.m. of $a$ and $18$.

Now we know that $\;\operatorname{lcm}(a,18)\times \gcd(a,18)=a\times 18$, whence
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,18)=\frac{a}{\gcd(18,a)}\times18,\enspace\text{so}\quad r=\frac{a}{\gcd(18,a)}.$$